# how can I Filter my Datagriview?

Tags: vb.net

Hello guys I am beginner and starting to learn codes anyway 
I created a form and use datagridview where my database data goes and also i created search textbox and search button. But I want to put a Filter on it so
If a user wants to search the studentname from Diamond class, so they choose Diamon in the first combobox. now they want to search Studentname from Diamon Class whose status is Absent, so they enter Absent in the second text box , and the data grid shows Student from Diamon Class whose status is Absent.
Can you help me please
Im using vb.net 1st programming language and ms access as a beginner?
I don't know how. Can you show me on how to do that

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ComboBox1.Text = "Diamon" Then
        If ComboBox2.Text = "StudentName" Then
            Attendance()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Attendance()
    Try
        Dim sCon As String = String.Format("Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db.accdb")
        Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE Attendance = @A1"
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Using con1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(sCon)
            con1.Open()
            Using cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, con1)
                With cmd1.Parameters
                    .Add("@A", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
                End With
                Dim adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1)
                adp.Fill(dt)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            End Using
            con1.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at the [RowFilter Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf19z8ze(v=vs.110).aspx?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.DataView.RowFilter)%3bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3dv4.6)%3bk(DevLang-VB)&rd=true&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) on the DefaultView of the datatable. `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "StudentName = '" & Combobox1.Text & "'"` Of course you would build this off of your combobox selections and search inputs.

Comment: I would suggest adding a `BindingSource` to your form, binding your `DataTable` to that and then binding that to your `DataGridView`.  You would then set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource` in the same way as the `RowFilter` property of the `DataView`. In fact, that's what it does under the hood anyway. Using a `BindingSource` has some other benefits too.

Comment: thanks Charles May I will read that and once I understand the code I give you a feedback. .

Comment: Hello Jmcilhinney I am sorry for your effort to go to waste, can you elaborate more for us so we can understand as beginner or can you show us how to do that any links.

Comment: @Charles I Figure it out but i know using this String method is not good. dv.RowFilter = "StudentName LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' And Attendance LIKE '%" + TextBox2.Text + "%'" <br/> But I want the combobox1 and the combobox2 to be the Identifier and the textbox1 and textbox2 to be the data of the columnName. Should I use IF condition. Im trying to look for the short way if it is possible? because I have a lot of column name.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the concatenation of strings in the rowfilter is safe from sql injection if that's what you mean. You really just limiting the original data shown by your filter. But did you try `dv.RowFilter = " + Combobox1.Text + " LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' AND " + Combobox2.Text + " LIKE '%" + TextBox2.Text + "%'"`

Comment: Yes already figure it out but have a little problem when I connect my 2 datetimepicker just like this            '    dv.RowFilter = ComboBox1.Text & "='" & TextBox1.Text & "' And " & ComboBox2.Text & "='" & TextBox2.Text & "' AND DateandTime1 BETWEEN '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' And " & DateTimePicker2.Value & "'"

can't figure out how to combine this. 'Syntax error: Missing operand before '=' operator.'
And is there a link on how can i learn on fixing it. Sorry for many question. I just want to learn

Comment: Update I already solve the problem rowfilter doesn't support Between Where clause